# How do I link the only the formatting between two cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets; `Sheet1` & `Sheet2` and want to link the format from `A1` `Sheet1` to `A1` `Sheet2`, i.e.

- `Sheet2` `A1` should match the formatting of `Sheet1` `A1`

I don't want to link the value, only the formatting.

I know I can link the value simply by going to `sheet2` and typing `=='Sheet1'!A1` in cell `A1`

**How do I link only the format?**

Comment: You can't do this with a formula.

Comment: Can you do it with a formula that runs every time the document is opened say?

Comment: Read BigBen's message again......  You would need to do it with VBA.

Comment: Sorry, long day. Formula was meant to be "vba".

Comment: Check the [`Workbook_Open`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.open) docs perhaps.

Comment: You tagged conditional-formatting. If that tag is accurate you may want to look into the rules that format the 2nd cell and use the same rule on the 1st. For example by changing the CF-rule into a formula.

Comment: A hack approach would be to define a new cell style and only apply it to those two cells - you would have to remember, though, to change the cell style (rather than using normal formatting options) whenever you wanted to change the format.

Answer (score 0):

This does the trick and can be adjusted as necessary but initially is copies the entire sheet then used Paste Special to paste only formats?

```
Sub CopyFormat()

'*** Copy the format of an entire sheet to another ***
'*** Should be run from WorkBook_Open event        ***

    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select '*** You could change workbooks here if desired
    Cells.Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                           Operation:=xlNone, _
                           SkipBlanks:=False, _
                           Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```